# How to properly refresh my Recycler List View

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, realm, swiperefreshlayout

I start using `RecyclerView` on my new school projects and `RealmDB` as data source. So far it is quite okay until i refresh the list view. here is [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmtAxN94who). There is black screen flashing happening because of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I can set white background instead of black if i want to make it less obvious.

But what mechanism should i be using to totally eliminate that obvious screen flashing ? I would be very much appreciate if i would obtain same result like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi7-WtHWvFk)

How do i refresh the list view so far ?

- STEP 1. I called web api to received posts
- STEP 2. Obtain the result and update or add it to #realm

  ```
  mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Realm realm) {
      for (Post post : posts) {
          //create post
          realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(post);
          //create common result row
          CommonResult cr = new CommonResult();
          int id = module.hashCode() + post.getId();
          cr.setId(id);
          cr.setPost(post);
          cr.setPostid(post.getId());
          cr.setTag(module.hashCode());
          realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(cr);
      }
  }
  }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess() {
     RealmResults<CommonResult> cr = mRealm.where(CommonResult.class)
         .equalTo("tag", module.hashCode())
         .findAll();
     mPostView.showListingView(cr, hasNext());
  }
  });
  ```
- STEP 3. Realm will notify the changes to adapter and the notify block will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on recycler adapter.

In My Adapter (`RecyclerView.Adapter`)

```
this.data.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<CommonResult>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<CommonResult> element) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I had changed `notifyDataSetChanged()` to `notifyItemChanged(i, element)`. The flashing is gone and animation become more smooth :-)

Comment: how and where are you calling onChange(---) method of listener

Comment: Hi @Rah, RealmDB will call this method automatically if there are changes inside this table.

Comment: can you please add some log inside onChange() method and check how many times the log getting trigger/print, because i thing you have so many records and this method is getting called multiple times

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is getting called for every post in `for (Post post : posts)`. Better call notifyDataSetChanged manually in the onSuccess block

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for the comments and I get it solved by eliminating the use of  `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

Changed from

```
this.data.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<CommonResult>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<CommonResult> element) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

to

```
 this.data.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<CommonResult>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<CommonResult> element) {
                notifyItems(element);
                Timber.i("onChange() called with: element = [" + element + "]");
            }
        });


private void notifyItems(RealmResults<CommonResult> element){
        for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
            notifyItemChanged(i, element.get(i));
        }
    }
```